# Is there some program to control fan speed in Ubuntu 14.04? - Acer Aspire 5740G

Tags: overheating, fan, alternative, fancontrol

I have an Acer Aspire 5740(G) that overheats constantly, even in normal use. After many hours of trying fan control utilities to speed up my fan, such as fancontrol and lm-sensors, and none of them working, I decided to finally ask this question. Is there a program like the Windows app, RWEverything, that does the same thing? I know how to use this to edit my ACPI table (I think) to force the fan to run at maximum speed, but I can't find anything that works with Ubuntu.

Even If there isn't, any fan control program that works is fine.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have cleaned the computer out, making sure there is no dust. The fan itself may be failing, but turning it up to its highest speed does help to keep the computer cooler.

EDIT: The BIOS settings have no mention of the fan at all.

Comment: You'd think this would be an easy 50 rep.

Comment: I set fan control speed via bios it's the best option as for me, check your bios/motherboard manufacturer if it has this feature you can set temperature manually like at what temperature to activate fan full speed and what is the temperature to maintain mid. speed etc.

Comment: I've already done that. There's nothing. @JoKeR

Comment: At acer-support there (usa or uk) you can ask for an *.iso image to download (fedora) and to check with this *.iso if your originally (and paid-by-you) acer is working with this .iso as live-CD (usb) + but acer-support only hands this iso out for reason in case you want to repair or you have a serious reason for this (like wrong processor or similiar).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue last year. Solution for me was to open up the laptop and vacumeclean it.

Problem is that, though these are called **Laptops** it is not wise to constantly have them located on your **Lap**.

Comment: I've already taken it apart and cleaned everything out; twice. I probably should have included this in the question, but whatever. I also never hold this thing in my lap, since it weighs about six pounds. Instead, I keep it propped up on my desk. I think the fan is probably failing and that's why its speed is so low normally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleaned inside the fan itself? You can screw the top off. Most of the time there is dust on the inside of the cooling raster that prevents the air from blowing through the metal to cool it.

Comment: I've taken it apart multiple times. The first time, there was some dust, but that didn't solve the problem. I think the fan is failing, but setting it to full speed still helps.

Comment: Didn't you see the first edit?

Comment: Zacharee1: It didn't specify if you also opened the fan itself.

Comment: OK. I thought it could be inferred.